# We are interested in price of a commodity, traded at regular intervals. Why it is reasonable to take $a$, $c$, and $d > 0$ and $b < 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, economics

We are interested in the price of a commodity which is traded at regular intervals. We let $Q_k$ denote the supply of commodity, $D_k$ the demand for the commodity, and $p_k$ the price at $k$-th time. The demand depends on the current price, $D_k = a + b p_k$ and the supply depends on the previous price, $Q_k = c + d p_{k - 1}$.

1. Explain why it is reasonable to take $a$, $c$, and $d$ to be positive and $b$ to be negative.
2. Suppose we make the assumption that the supply is always equal to the demand. Find the difference equation satisfied by the sequence $\{p_k\}$.

Okay after some research I feel as though I may have a start to answering the first question. If you know how supply and demand works you basically want supply high because its graph generates an increasing function where as the demand graph generates a decreasing function.

I'm still not positive about question one but think I have an answer for question two if anyone could confirm or deny it would be great, set $Q_k$ = $D_k$ then solve for $p_k$ I get $p_k$ = $\frac{c - a + dp_{k-1}}{b}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can assume $b$ is negative, as demand decreases as price increases. Intuitively, we have an initial demand if something is free. If we are getting paid to get something, don't we demand more of it? If we are paying for it, wouldn't we demand less of it? Think of $a$ as an initial endowment.

Similarly, with $c, d > 0$, a higher price incentivizes the producer to supply more product, so $Q_{k}$ increases with $p_{k-1}$. Similarly, if price goes down, the producer won't make as much, so won't produce as much. The constant $c$ is how much the producer would make if $p_{k} = 0$. So if a business is starting up, they have to make the product to sell, right? So $c > 0$.

Does this make sense?

**Edit**: Your answer for $p_{k}$ is correct.

Let's talk about the story a bit more. So at equilibrium, we have $D_{k} = Q_{k}$. People are demanding exactly what is being supplied. Now suppose I increase the price. Then the supplier, based off the previous iteration's demand, is incentivized to produce more of the good. If I know $50$ people bought my good at \$2 per item, then at \$3 per item, I make an extra \$50. That's what the supplier sees.

Now those who demand the good react to the price at the current iteration. If it costs more, demand decreases, if nothing else than due to the budget constraint. You can only afford so much, correct? So now fewer than $50$ people demand the good, and the supplier has excess good and there is a difference between $D_{k}$ and $Q_{k}$.

Does that clarify some more?

Comment: Kind of sort of, basically I have to look at it in terms of a company starting to sell I new product. So since they have just starting producing a new product there is not a demand yet?

Comment: That would assume $b = -a$ or $p_{0} = 0$. That's not always the case. There could be demand for a product not yet on the market, or the company could pre-sell before the product is ready. Think of it in terms of market friction and equilibrium.

Comment: Still have some trouble making sense of it, I feel like I'm getting close but still confused.

Comment: Can you clarify more as to your confusion?

Comment: Yes, for sure, first off a,b,c,d are just some constants correct? These constants are arbitrary with the exception of of a,c,d > 0 and b < 0? Most importantly I just can't make sense of the relationship between the demand price always being less then supply price. Is it because we always want the supply greater than the demand so companies can generate more revenue by selling a high supply at the previous demand price?

Comment: I apologize if my questions sound thick or I'm completely missing the concept here.

Comment: Just to clarify, since someone edited your post for formatting, is $Q_{k} = c + dp_{k-1}$, the price from the previous iteration; or is $Q_{k} = c + dp_{k} - 1$, the price from iteration $k$ minus $1$?

Comment: Yes , im sorry about that was actually me who edited it , I previously didn't know how to make both the k and -1 into subscript but I went off your example with the curly braces and learned. It is the price from the previous iteration.

Comment: I've updated to better explain. Please let me know if this helps some, or if I can clarify more!

Comment: That helped a lot but I still don't understand why its reasonable for b to be negative an a,c,d positive.

Comment: So if price increases, what will happen to demand? What will happen to supply? That should explain $b$ and $d$. With $a, c$, I would say that it makes sense for them to be non-negative. A zero demand makes sense, but does a negative demand? What about a negative supply?

Comment: So if price increases demand decreases, and supply increases. So we must make the assumption that price is increasing rather than decreasing. For a,c negative supply and demand just wouldn't make sense.

Comment: We don't have to make the assumption that price is increasing. Look at gas prices. The trend is that they've increased. But is it cheaper to gas up one week as opposed to the next? Many times, yes. You could very well have prices fluctuating in some sort of periodic trend.

Comment: Nice example , I gotcha thanks this was all very helpful

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)

Comment: @ ml0105 if you get a chance could you check this out http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754015/suppose-that-the-sequence-of-pricesp-k-converges-to-a-limiting-price-bar-p